# Flexbox align-self property not transitioning?

Tags: css, css-transitions, flexbox

I've tried creating a morphin "button", which slides on a further menu.
The idea was based on Codrops [Morphing Buttons Concept](http://tympanus.net/Development/ButtonComponentMorph/index5.html)

Now It's almost set up and there are only 2 minor things that annoy me:

- When "closing" the menu the buttons drop to the bottom **immidiately** although I've set the
  *align-items* property in the transition. Does Flexbox not support transition   on said property?
- The glyphicon doesn't adjust itself with *align-items* and *justify-center* therefore I've had to get it done *dirty* by adjusting the top property.

I'm kinda out of ideas..

[JSBin example](http://jsbin.com/kiwulaqopu/1/edit?html,css,output)

Comment: No. 'align-items'  is not transitionable

Comment: Flexbox `align-self` is not an animatable property as given in the [**MDN align-self**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-self) and [**w3.org Property def Align-self**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#propdef-align-self**).

Comment: Is there any way to simulate this? Maybe with a margin transition?

Comment: Your JSBin no longer renders the output because it says your bin expired. Add your [mcve] in the question if you need help.

Comment: why isn't it animatable???